# Javascript button with in For Loop in Razor view

Tags: javascript, razor

I Have the following code within my razor view that I want to action a button next to every response.

Once clicked I want it to copy response to actualresponse.

But I get the following error

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'foo': object is null or undefined.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Responses.Count(); i++)
     {
         <div class="col-md-4">
              @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.Responses[i].Response, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label"})
              @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.Responses[i].Response)
         </div>

         <input type="button" name="set_Value" id="@i" value="Copy Response to Actual Response" class="btn btn-success" dataset-foo="@Model.Responses[i].Response" onclick="setVale(this)" />

         <div class="col-md-4">
              @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.Responses[i].ActualResponse, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label"})
              @Html.TextAreaFor(x => Model.Responses[i].ActualResponse, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "from-control", @id = "actualResponse-" + i, rows = 5, columns = 40})
         </div>

         <script type="text/javascript">
              function setValue(btn) 
                 {
                    var id = btn.id;
                    var value = btn.value;
                    var foo = btn.dataset.foo;
                    document.getElementById('actualResponse-' + id).value = foo
                 }
         </script>

      }
```

Comment: You have multiple elements with the ID 'actualResponse'.  You should make them unique by appending the current index, e.g. actualResponse0, actualResponse1, ...

Comment: @RobPurcell Ive amended the post to show how Ive managed to reference the different id's which now works, however it only copies the last Response to any of the ActualResposes not the correctly related one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop creates multiple copies of a function with the same name. The last function with the hardcoded id is the result you see.

You could just pass `this` into your click handler.

```
<input type="button" name="set_Value"
       value="Copy Response to Actual Response" class="btn btn-success" 
       id = "@i"
       data-foo = "@foo"
       onclick="setVale(this)" />
```

Then you can stop that ugly mixing of Razor and JavaScript. And take the function out of the for loop so you only have one `setValue()` which will handle all instances of your buttons.

```
function setValue(btn) {
    var id = btn.id;
    var value = btn.value;
    var foo = btn.dataset.foo;
}
```

Comment: Using that I get an error saying it can't find the value of foo

Comment: foo is just a fake variable. You probably don't have that defined. You could replace that with an actual property from your model.

Comment: Hi I did keeping foo as the name but still get an error

Comment: What is the source of the error (browser, server)? What is the exact error message?

Comment: Fixed, the issue was IE9 doesnt support dataset I instead replaced it with btn.getAttribute('data-foo');

Comment: You still need to move the script block out of the for loop. Otherwise, you will be redefining the same function multiple times.